# React + MobX - not re-rendering update to state

Tags: meteor, reactjs, reactive-programming, observable, mobx

I've setup a new sample/boilerplate project for testing out using Meteor with React & MobX (using Mantra architecture). The project is at https://github.com/markoshust/mantra-matui-mobx

I'm having an issue where the state change of the State.header.title property is not properly reflecting the updated state change on re-render.

My state is built by pulling in simple objects:
https://github.com/markoshust/mantra-matui-mobx/blob/master/client/modules/core/stores/route.js

Into one master observable object:
https://github.com/markoshust/mantra-matui-mobx/blob/master/client/main.js#L8

I'm listing for route change and calling an action to update state:
https://github.com/markoshust/mantra-matui-mobx/blob/master/client/modules/core/reactions/route.js#L10

This action updates state:
https://github.com/markoshust/mantra-matui-mobx/blob/master/client/modules/core/actions/route.js#L5

The console is logging out proper state change, so the state is being updated properly. However, the component is not being re-rendered with the updated state (this line is console.log'ing old state val):
https://github.com/markoshust/mantra-matui-mobx/blob/master/client/modules/core/containers/Header.js#L6

I'm seeing the 'updating...' message, so the component is re-rendering, but it appears to still be pulling in the old state. I did add `observer` to all of my react components:
https://github.com/markoshust/mantra-matui-mobx/blob/master/client/modules/core/components/Header.js

Comment: I seem to have fixed the issue with a custom withMobx composer, the only thing it's doing is waiting on the next tick to render the component. Any idea why this fixes it? Mobx is supposed to be syncronous.

https://github.com/markoshust/mantra-matui-mobx/blob/master/client/modules/core/libs/with_mobx.js#L5

Comment: I think `State.header` is observable, but not `State.header.title`.

Comment: Tried this, no change

Comment: Can you show me the code how you tried it? There might be some mistake.

Comment: You can check out the repo code & history. I did convert the child stores to observable objects, but this was rather an architectural decision rather than a needed one. The root issue is there was nothing to tell the composer to rerun, due to mobx's automagical update process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to create a custom composer for MobX. I added a listen for autorun to re-compose the component.

https://github.com/markoshust/mantra-matui-mobx/blob/master/client/modules/core/libs/with_mobx.js

```js
import { compose } from 'mantra-core';
import { autorun } from 'mobx';

export default function composeWithMobx(fn, L, E, options) {
  const onPropsChange = (props, onData) => {
    const reactiveFn = () => fn(props, onData);
    autorun(reactiveFn);
    return reactiveFn();
  };
  return compose(onPropsChange, L, E, options);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I just arrived in NL again. I saw that some of the links in the original links are broken. If you can provide links to the original commit, I gladly take a look at the original solution to investigate why it didn't work as expected

Comment: Hi @mweststrate, thanks, updated the links! Changed a few things around since I posted. Everything works now, but only with the composeWithRedux composer (which includes autorun() call). Should I not need autorun for this to work?

Comment: No autorun should be fine I think. Note that the returned disposer should best be called when the component is disposed.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the answer so it returns the disposer/autorun. I believe this is good.

Comment: Updated to properly return the disposer

Comment: Note that the disposer is the function returned from the autorun, not the original one ;-)

Comment: @mweststrate that's actually what I initially had, however when I returned the autorun, my cleanup function wasn't being executed.

Comment: I renamed disposer to reactiveFn, as the cleanup function only executes when the result of that is returned.